# Choice of prior and combination with likelihood, sample from exp distribution

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, prior

I am taking a course in Statistical Theory of Science. We have an exercise where we are comparing "Classical" and Bayesian parameter estimation.

We have a sample $(x_1,...,x_5) = (0.28,0.30,0.94,0.42,1.76)$ from an exponential distribution with parameter $\theta$, the pdf is given as

$$f(x|\theta) =\theta e^{-\theta x}, \quad \theta, x > 0$$

We need to estimate $\theta$ by choosing an appropriate prior, combining it with the likelihood and estimating it from the posterior distribution.

My question is about the prior, what would be *appropriate*? My guess is that it should be a Gamma distribution based on the fact that our parameter exists in $\mathbb{R}^+$. Is this correct?

If the above is correct, am I supposed to add a guess for the parameters in the Gamma? Or should they stay as variables?

How do I interpret "combine with the likelihood", is this the calculation of the posterior?

Comment: Any prior is "appropriate". There are no good and bad priors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gamma prior is certainly a good option as it is conjugate with the exponential likelihood. This means that the posterior will also be a Gamma distribution, and the update (prior $\rightarrow$ posterior) do not rely on any simulation.

Say you have a prior $\Gamma(a,b)$ whose density is:

$$
p(\theta ; a,b) \propto \theta^{a-1}e^{-\theta b}
$$

and the exponential likelihood based on observations $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$:
\begin{align*}
p(X \mid \theta) &= \prod \theta e^{-\theta X_i} \\
&= \theta^n e^{-\theta \sum X_i}
\end{align*}

What we are interested in is the posterior distribution of $\theta$, that is the distribution of $\theta$ *after observing the data*.
We get this posterior from the bayes theorem:
$$
p(\theta \mid X) = \frac{p(\theta) p(X \mid \theta)}{p(X)}
$$
which is sometimes written as $p(\theta \mid X) \propto p(\theta) p(X \mid \theta)$.
 Here $p(\theta)$ is the prior distribution and $p(X \mid \theta)$ is the likelihood of the model.

Thus the posterior distribution of $\theta \mid X$ is proportional to the product of the prior and the likelihood (and I think this is what is meant by *combine with the likelihood*):
\begin{align*}
p(\theta \mid X) &\propto p(\theta ; a,b) p(X \mid \theta) \\
& \propto \theta^{a-1}e^{-\theta b} \theta^n e^{-\theta \sum X_i} \\
& \propto \theta^{a+n-1} e^{-\theta(b+\sum X_i)}
\end{align*}
The last line, seen as a function of $\theta$, is proportional to the density of a $\Gamma(a+n, b+ \sum X_i)$, which is the posterior distribution of $\theta$.

The posterior is completely determined an you can easily compute posterior mean/median or credible intervals without relying on any simulation.

You have to choose the parameter $(a,b)$ for the prior distribution of $\theta$. This should reflect you *prior belief* on the plausible values of $\theta$. This parameters $(a,b)$ are fixed, but can sometimes be considered themselves as random, but this is advanced bayesian statistics.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, very good! If I do not have any prior belief, as this is just an exercise with no context, what numbers for $a$ and $b$ would make a good choice? We are supposed to compare the result with estimation using MLE.

Comment: To repeat myself, there is no good or bad choice of $(a,b)$. Bayesian analysis is relative to the prior measure, the posterior indicates how the data modifies this prior measure. Within Bayesian analysis it thus makes no sense to compare two priors.